# Reading The Browser URL in AS3?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, apache-flex, flex3

My application is integrated with the Other application as a Tab in the IFrame of Parent Application.

I want To read the Browser Address Bar URL.

Is it Possible to read.

```
<iframe id="myIFrameID123" src="http://192.168.1.102:8080/om/om.html?ucode=" width="100%" height="600"></iframe>
```

And trying to Access the Parent app URL

```
var search:String = ExternalInterface.call("window.location.search.toString");
var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(search);
```

If its possible to Read the address Bar URL ll be Fine...
Both app running in Different JBOS.

Answer (score 2):

" *If its possible to Read the address Bar URL*"

Yes it is possible using:

```
import flash.external.*;
var curUrl:String =  String( ExternalInterface.call(" function(){ return document.location.href.toString();}"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you seem to be using Flex, there is no need for JavaScript injection. You can use an [IBrowserManager](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/IBrowserManager.html) to access this information:

```
var url:String = BrowserManager.getInstance().url;
```

This interface offers quite a few other possibilities to interact with the browser, which you can read about in [the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/IBrowserManager.html).